# How to include Eclipse themes in an Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse based codebase, that both work as a plugin, and as an Eclipse RCP (standalone application).

When the plugin is inside Eclipse, the plugin UI benefits from Eclipse bundled themes. However when the RCP application is launched, there is no them bundled.

[image: JMC-Apperance]

The rcp `plugin.xml` file contains a reference to the default css theme, but this doesn't seem to help.

```xml
<?eclipse version="3.0"?>
<plugin>
    ...
    
    <extension
             point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products"
             id="product">
       ...
       <product
             application="org.openjdk.jmc.rcp.application.app"
             name="%APPLICATION_NAME">
    
          <property
                name="cssTheme"
                value="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.theme.e4_default">
          </property>
```

So what I'd like is to include the default theme, like in the regular Eclipse, like this:

[image]

---

I am a total rookie to Eclipse. So I miss a lot of concepts and reflexes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The themes come from plug-ins using the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme` extension point. The `org.eclipse.ui.themes` plug-in defines the standard ones - is that included in the RCP?

Comment: Mmmh I don't think so, there's this line in the RCP MANIFEST file `org.eclipse.ui.themes;resolution:=optional`. I'll look where to add these as I'm not accustomed to Eclipse dependency management, likely in some eclipse file (maybe the `.target` file), and probably in maven/tycho.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you that did it. I just had to add `<plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.themes" download-size="0" install-size="0" version="0.0.0"/>` to the application feature file, declare `org.eclipse.ui.themes` (without the optional resolution) in the RCP application manifest. And exactly the same for `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme`. If you write an answer I'll approve it. Many thanks !